# how to find same two special character in a fields in impala

Tags: hive, impala

I have a case statement which derive specific portion of string field based on the condition.

example:

```
customer_id
7115878969-127881041-000000
650030087-1
130715315-1
2956599329-154074046-000000
127243855-1
```

Please find my current code below:

```
case 
        when substr(reverse(trim(customer_id)),1,instr(reverse(trim(customer_id)),'-')-1)='000000'
        then split_part(customer_id, '-', 2)
        when substr(reverse(trim(customer_id)),1,instr(reverse(trim(customer_id)),'-')-1)<>'000000'
        then trim(substr(customer_id,1,instr(customer_id,'-')-1))
        --else  'error' 
    end as PN
```

,

it check right side'000000'. but I need to change the condition based on the"-"
if two "-" then 127881041 middle portion of two"-"
if one "-" then 650030087

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: Please be careful when tagging and not just tag everything. If this is a database question which DBMS are you actually working with???

Comment: Are you saying that if there are 2 dashes in the data you need to return something otherwise something else? Is this right? If so, what is that "something"?

Comment: Yes.I have two type of customer_id like 650029305-1 and  7115878969-127881041-000000. I need to check if it is two "-" then 127881041 else 650029305.thanks